# good programming practice -- which is more efficient?

Tags: performance, lua

I find myself programming more functionally than iteratively, and often write functions that repeat a calculation. For example,

```
function DoThis(a)
    if something(a) - another(a) - yetanother(a) > 0 then 
        return something(a) - another(a) - yetanother(a) 
    else 
        return 0 
    end 
end
```

I do this a lot, if the result is not going to be used more than a few times.  Is it more efficient, generally, to assign the calculation to a variable?

```
function DoThis(a)
    local x = something(a) - another(a) - yetanother(a)
    if x > 0 then 
        return x 
    else 
        return 0 
    end 
end
```

I understand the difference in this case is probably negligible, but I'm interested in developing good habits from the beginning, and as things pile up and complicate, the difference could be sizeable.

Comment: "I understand the difference in this case is probably negligible," Well, that depends. a) does the compiler/interpreter perhaps compute the thing only once? [Only legitimate if it knows that there are no side effects] b) how costly are the called functions? If the called functions have no side effects [and the result is small, if the language uses lazy evaluation], always play it safe and assign the result to a local so that it needs to be computed only once.

Comment: I'm not sure where lua falls on this spectrum.  But I like the sound of playing it safe!

Comment: I'd prefer `return math.max(0, something(a) - another(a) - yetanother(a))` without additional variables.

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff How delightfully out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the result of a computation (return value of a function) more than once it is almost always a good idea to store it in a variable instead of recalculating it. Especially if the function is very complex and thus needs long to compute recalls should be avoided in order to improve performance.

Comment: That makes sense, if I need to use the result more than once, to store it for later. I guess my question has to do with hardware, and if it is physically more taxing for a computer to read/write to memory than to perform a calculation. I suppose you're right that it depends on the calculation. Is there an accepted rule for when to use one as opposed to the other? If this function is in the main loop, it could run continuously and should be as efficient as possible.

Comment: I think the general rule is to avoid recomputation if possible. Even if you assume that read/write takes more time than the computation itself this should be faster:
If you assign something to a local variable this variable is created on the stack. If you return a value from a function this value is pushed onto the stack in the called function to be popped from it by the caller. 
As you see in both cases data gets written to (the same kind of) memory.

Comment: So at best, you kinda break even. That's really good to know, thanks for your insight.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you really understood what I said.
If you assign a value to a local variable you write to the stack.
If you (re)call a function you: push your parameters on the stack; push the return address on the stack; do the computation again (depending on the function probably the worst thing); push the return value on the stack; and eventually return to the caller where you pop the return value.

So recalling a function is more expensive than storing the value.

Comment: Oh, i see-- but, in this case, I wouldn't be calling the function again, just reaccomplishing the calculation -- but that's the _worst_ thing, and I should clearly avoid it. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you should avoid it. Storing values you need more than once in local variables won't hurt you an will give you better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Once you start getting nitty gritty this question gets pretty interesting. Each of those code samples you gave can be more efficient than the other in certain conditions. In the case that

```
something(a) - another(a) - yetanother(a)
```

is always less than or equal to zero the first code sample will be slightly more efficient because you avoid the assignment to a variable, so the number never leaves the registers used for calculation.

If that statement is ever greater than zero, however, then the second code sample with be much more significantly efficient since you avoid 3 whole function calls which require at least a stack frame to be set up with variables and a return. If your functions are worse than O(1) efficiency then the difference will be even more pronounced.

If someone wants to do speed tests with some functions from different efficiency classes I would be interested in the results and it should help illustrate my points.

Comment: That's quite helpful.  If this funtion returns zero most of the time, the first is slightly more efficient, otherwise the second is vastly more efficient?  I suppose to hedge my bets I'd better just use assignments every which-way.

Comment: The second is more efficient enough that if there is any small chance that the function will not return 0 it will be better to use assignments. Also it's better style.